# Split wordpress loop to multiple layouts

Tags: loop, customization, query

OK so I've searched a lot and couldn't find a straight forward answer to my question.
I am simply trying to use one category loop that will display posts in a category page in a wordpress site. lets say 6 posts for this purpose.

it's pretty simple to accomplish it by using a simple query loop like so:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
// content or anything comes here
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

however, I am trying to "break" my loop into 2 different layouts:

1. 2 posts showing with featured image
2. the rest of the 4 in a different design which will be just showing title + excerpt + read more

Here is a sample which best demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4405634/split-loop-layout.jpg

There are tons of solutions in the web, however some of the are too complicated and some don't work in a category loop.

I have seen it in a lot of websites and still can't find a simple way of doing it.
does someone have a nice solution?

Thanks a lot.
Gil

Comment: I think @milo has answer, but one thing to mention - `query_post()` is [Bad practice](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/17968), Use `pre_get_post` filter instead.

Comment: Try using "offset" - see my answer below.

Comment: **Please** go back and **work on your older questions too**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create 2 queries using the "offset" parameter and separate them by:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Display posts from the 4th one (offset is starting from 0):

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'offset=3' ) ); ?>
```

EDIT: Here's some sample code:

```
<?php query_posts('offset=0&showposts=2&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php query_posts('offset=2&showposts=4&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

That's it. You'll have 2 posts which you can style any way you want, and the next four, which, again, you can style differently.

Comment: can you write a sample of a working code? I am not that coder and not sure where to start. it will be great! thanks!

Comment: Why the negative vote? There are more ways to separate 2 queries and this is one of them.

Comment: Dont really remember why. it was long time ago when I rated it. anyway - it didn't work for me. I found another solution. changed your rating to positive.

Comment: This method/answer is by far inferior  to the others
as it requires you to do two separate queries. There is no need for that - Just count the index and apply the featured_template to count<=2.
See Milo's or Syed Balkhi's answers...

Comment: @Ciprian how would you break the loop to add an advertisement between a certain post number.

Answer (score 5):

check which post you're currently outputting via `$wp_query->current_post`:

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

                // first two post to show both title, excerpt
                if( 2 > $wp_query->current_post ) :
                    the_title();
                    the_excerpt();

                //else (remaining) show only title    
                else :
                    the_title();
                endif;

        endwhile;
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo  tried your code but it didn't work, it gave me an error.

Comment: @gilhamer check for syntax error, coz this code is correct.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. can you tell me how do I put the_title in the first post and the_excerpt in the second one?  thanks

Comment: put `the_title();` after `if( 2 > $wp_query->current_post ) :` to print it for first 2 posts and `the_excerpt();` after `else :` to show on remaining posts.

Comment: Hi Amit, your code really works, however, I have so much extra HTML to put in between and in this way of coding it makes it very complicated since you need to deal with echoing a lot of stuff and a lot of single and regular quotation marks. I will try anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: @gilhamer - you don't need to echo everything, you can close php to output your markup then open it again. see [escaping from html](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Comment: I am a little noob. is it OK if you edit your code just a little so I can understand how it works? (let's say just use and empty DIV for demonstration) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily by using a counter in your loop like this:

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$myquery = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );
while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); 

if($counter == 1) { ?>

First post Look Different

<?php } else { ?>

Rest looks different

<?php
}
$counter++;
endwhile;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: this was actually working @Syed Balkhi  but the problem is that it shows all posts regardless if I am in a certain category. I would like to get the first 6 posts but according to a certain category I am in.  is it possible?

Comment: You can count posts directly in the query using `$wp_query->current_post +1;`

Comment: can you please edit your code so I know where exactly to put it?  thanks!